# SAS: PROC IMPORT: CSV WITH DATES AS VAR NAMES

Tags: sas

I'm importing CSV data in the following format:

```
SEDOL,12/08/2009,13/08/2009,14/08/2009,17/08/2009,18/08/2009
B1YVN39,7.8431,7.8431,7.8431,7.8431,7.598
B00G7R3,3.8,3.61,3.81,3.81,3.81
2965237,4.5351,4.5351,4.5351,4.5351,4.5351
2554345,7.355,7.355,7.355,7.355,7.355
```

I'm using the following command:

```
PROC IMPORT OUT= want
            DATAFILE= have 
            DBMS=CSV REPLACE;
RUN;
```

Then transposing the data to long format, as follows:

```
PROC SORT DATA=want OUT=want; BY SEDOL;RUN; 
proc transpose data=want out=transp;
    by SEDOL;
run;
proc print; run;
```

How can I import the dates correctly formatted and change the variable type from default to date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importing and transposing are handy procedures, but if you understand your data well, a little data step program can deal with this in one step:

```
data want(keep=sedol v_date v_value);
  infile have dsd dlm=',' truncover;

  informat sedol $8. d1-d50 ddmmyy10. v1-v50 8.;
  format v_date yymmdd10.;

  array d(50) d1-d50;
  array v(50) v1-v50;
  /* Retain the date values and the count of dates */ 
  retain d1-d50 idx;

  /* Read header */
  if _n_ = 1 then do; 
     input sedol d1-d50;
     /* loop to find how many date columns there are */
     do idx=1 to 50 while(d(idx) ne .);
        end;
     idx = idx - 1; /* must subtract one here */
     delete;
     end;

  /* Read data lines */
  input sedol v1-v50;
  do i=1 to idx;
     v_date  = d(i);
     v_value = v(i);
     output;
     end;
run;
```

As long as your input file is exactly as you describe (a header record with a leading ID variable less than 8 characters followed by some number of date values representing columns), this will process up to 50 measurements.  It should be easy enough to modify if your needs change.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest in this case importing separately data and headers.

First, we import data:

```
PROC IMPORT OUT= want
    DATAFILE= "C:\have.csv" 
    DBMS=CSV REPLACE;
    getnames=no;
    datarow=2;
RUN;
```

Then we import only the first row with variables' names:

```
options obs=1;
PROC IMPORT OUT= header
    DATAFILE= "C:\have.csv" 
    DBMS=CSV REPLACE;
    getnames=no;
RUN;
options obs=max;
```

Then we transpose row with headers into column and "mask" illegal (as SAS-names) values - add letter (doesn't matter which one, I chose 'D') as the first character and replace all slashes '/' to underscores '_':

```
proc transpose data=header out=header(drop=_name_);var _all_;run;
data header;
    set header;
    if anydigit(substr(COL1,1,1)) then COL1=cats("D",COL1);
    COL1=translate(COL1,"_","/");
run;
```

Put this new 'cleaned' column names into a macrovariable:

```
proc sql noprint;
    select COL1 into :names separated by ' '
    from header;
quit;
```

And generate DATA-step for renaming using CALL EXECUTE routine:

```
data _null_;
    dsid=open("want","i");
    num=attrn(dsid,"nvars");
    call execute("data want;");
    call execute("set want;");
    call execute("rename");
    do i=1 to num;
        call execute(varname(dsid,i)||"="||scan("&names",i," "));
    end;
    call execute(";run;");
    rc=close(dsid);
run;
```

Now your original SORT and TRANSPOSE:

```
PROC SORT DATA=want OUT=want; BY SEDOL;RUN; 
proc transpose data=want out=transp;
    by SEDOL;
run;
```

And at last 'unmask' those dates back (deleting first D and replacing _ to /), and covert them to real dates with INPUT(). RETAIN statement is added just to put the new variable DATE at the second place right after SEDOl.

```
data transp;
    retain SEDOL date;
    set transp;
    substr(_name_,1,1)='';
    _name_=translate(_name_,"/","_");
    date=input(strip(_name_),ddmmyy10.);
    drop _name_;
    format date ddmmyy10.;
run;
```